# How to use requests to get data from this page?

Tags: python, html, http, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to use the requests method to get real estates information from [this page](https://www.barratthomes.co.uk/?qloc=London%2C%20%E8%8B%B1%E5%9B%BD).

What I did is that I tried to find the correct HTTP request sent during the page loading.

First, I used the street address of the first property as keyword to do a search in the Chrome debug tool. However, nothing containing the keywords was found.

Then, I manually looked at the HTTP requests happened during the loading process, and I found [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/DistanceMatrixService.GetDistanceMatrix?1m3&1m2&1d51.5073509&2d-0.12775829999998223&2m3&1m2&1d51.4993&2d-0.10460000000000491&2m3&1m2&1d51.4816&2d-0.12829999999996744&2m3&1m2&1d51.5085&2d-0.08100000000001728&2m3&1m2&1d51.5143&2d-0.07110000000000127&2m3&1m2&1d51.5574&2d-0.19429999999999836&2m3&1m2&1d51.5141&2d-0.2499000000000251&2m3&1m2&1d51.5775&2d-0.2417000000000371&2m3&1m2&1d51.5328&2d0.03719999999998436&2m3&1m2&1d51.6086&2d-0.21039999999993597&2m3&1m2&1d51.6049&2d-0.24329999999997654&2m3&1m2&1d51.6176&2d-0.2199000000000524&2m3&1m2&1d51.3784&2d-0.15779999999995198&2m3&1m2&1d51.5802&2d-0.33590000000003783&2m3&1m2&1d51.4701&2d-0.36360000000001946&2m3&1m2&1d51.5932&2d-0.3450000000000273&2m3&1m2&1d51.5017&2d-0.4216999999999871&2m3&1m2&1d51.5017&2d-0.4216999999999871&2m3&1m2&1d51.3148&2d-0.14369999999996708&2m3&1m2&1d51.7917&2d0.14980000000002747&2m3&1m2&1d51.3686&2d-0.7854999999999563&3e0&6szh-CN&7e1&callback=_xdc_._yf8b3n&key=AIzaSyBgXULS--nlOSVcpkLFGYx0Vz6QXsaCqEg&token=110518).

There is location information in its response:

```
"destination_addresses" : [
  "St George's Circus (Stop Y), London SE1 8EH英国",
  "62 Wandsworth Rd, Nine Elms, London SW8 2LF英国",
  "1 Water Ln, London EC3R 6EA英国",
  "Leman Street (Stop OH), Whitechapel, London E1 8ER英国",
  "17 Kidderpore Ave, London NW3 7SF英国",
  "12 Western Ave, East Acton, London W3 7UD英国",
  "47 Franklin House, Tyrrel Way, London NW9 7QA英国",
  "The Presbytery, Green St, Upton Park, London E13 9AX英国",
  "1 Bittacy Rd, London NW7 1BP英国",
  "7 Coxwell Boulevard, London NW9 4AB英国",
  "National Institute for Medical Research, London NW7 1AA英国",
  "45 Hackbridge Rd, Wallington SM6 7AY英国",
  "28A College Rd, Harrow HA1 1BE英国",
  "4 Balfour Rd, Hounslow TW3 1JX英国",
  "3312 Headstone Dr, Harrow HA1 4UP英国",
  "6 Nestles Ave, Hayes UB3 4QA英国",
  "6 Nestles Ave, Hayes UB3 4QA英国",
  "Keats Way, Coulsdon CR5 3FL英国",
  "Marsh Ln, Harlow CM17英国",
  "23 Cricket Field Grove, Crowthorne RG45 7ES英国"
```

However, the address here is different from what is displayed on the page.

For example, the first address in the response

```
"St George's Circus (Stop Y), London SE1 8EH"
```

is displayed/transformed as

```
"Blackfriars Road, Southwark, LONDON, GREATER LONDON, SE1 8EQ"
```

on the page.

Can anyone tell me how to use requests to get the data as it is displayed on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use same API listed in the html.

[image]

This API looks like it is used to retrieve info from when you submit via search bar.

You get all the listing info though I am only printing out address as requested. Advantage - you get all results for search.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.barratthomes.co.uk/api/search/developments/bar/?additionalBrands=bar,bln').json()

for listing in r['results']:
    print(listing['adr'])
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please share the process how you found this api?

Comment: I inspected the html as shown above. Looking at the attribute values decided it was associated with search and gave it a try.

Comment: Thanks. However, do you know why we can't find this api in the Network tab of Chrome dev tools?

Comment: Did you try manually entering values and submitting via search?

Comment: yes, I tried. I used the property information as keywords and put it in the search form of Chrome devTools, but could not find that api. (Normally, it should work, but it didn't work for this site.)

Comment: sorry, I clicked that by mistake.